# Compare two N-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have two sets of N-dimensional arrays which I need to somehow compare and obtain a value that represents how "similar" they are. In statistical terms this is a two-sample goodness of fit problem where the hypothesis is that the two arrays are derived from the same parent distribution.

To simplify, imagine 2-dimensional arrays like the ones shown below:

[image]

for which I need to present a number that quantifies how "similar" they are.

Is there a `python` package that provides such a statistical test? I'm open to using `numpy`, `scipy`, `scikit-learn`, etc.

---

**Add**

I've found a `scipy` package that apparently does what I need but it only works on 1-D arrays: [scipy.stats.ks_2samp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html). The `R` statistical software has the [ks package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/ks.pdf) which includes the `kde.test` function. This function does what I need but I'd like a `python` implementation.

Comment: How rigorous does it need to be? For a simple metric, you could always compare the means and covariance matrix.

Comment: There are a plethora of ways for comparing point clouds. E.g., calculating the distances of means (``np.mean()``) would tell you how far their centers are apart. Calculating the determinant of the covariance matrix (``np.cov()``)  would describe the volume of an approximated ellipsoid.

Comment: You may be able to use the `kstest` module from scipy to do a 'goodness-of-fit' for your matrices.

Comment: This isn't a statistics site, so you won't get reliable advice about how to compare them.  Of course, if you have a particular two-sample goodness-of-fit statistic in mind, then I'm sure we could help you implement it, and `scipy.stats` probably has it.

Comment: *such a statistical test* is vague. check http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Some more information about the context might be helpful - 'similarity' can mean a lot of things. The 3 approaches which come to my mind are: 1) do some form of kernel density estimation and then look at e.g. the Pearsons correlation coefficient on the resulting images 2) look at a pairwise correlation (e.g. Ripley's K - or some extension thereof) 3) building on @Dietrich's solution - look at the principle components/axes of the cloud and the moments about these.

Comment: @Everybody, I've updated the question with some more information which I believe answer the questions made here. Please let me know if it doesn't and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about belongs on stats SE instead.

Comment: I'm asking about a `python` implementation of a statistical test similar to `scipy.stats.ks_2samp` or `kde.test` for more than 1-D. The folks over at SE will not necessarily have this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know of an R package that does the trick, would it work for your application to call R from Python?  The `rpy2` package allows you to communicate with R (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpy2/), and if you're using IPython, you can do so interactively using `rmagic` (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/rmagic.html).  There's also some experimental `rpy2` support in `pandas`. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/r_interface.html